# Mouse Handlers during "spawn" drag with SVG shapes

Tags: javascript, css, svg, mouselistener

I am continuing elaborating my little project and learning javascript & svg.

In my last code i implemented "click to spawn element and drag it" by creating a copy (cloneNode(true)) of the clicked object and then re-assigning it to the draggable.

Now that I refactored whole code to leverage javascript object factory I seems have stuck trying to figure the proper "loop";(

Try the snipped below:
- i managed to create draggables (inventory shapes)
- i managed to add some logic to recognize if its inventory class and do the copy and change class to "draggable"
- now two issues:
-- spawned objects are not really full copies of the original Draggables, hence they don't have mouse listeners and I am not sure how to detach the listeners from original objects...

How do you ppl code all that?

```js
//var morphUIon = false;
var morphTarget = null;
var canvas = {};
var inventory = {};
canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
inventory = document.getElementById("inventory");

window.onload = function() { 
  var src = document.querySelectorAll(".inventory");
    for (var h = 0; h < src.length; h++) {
      var o = new Draggable(src[h]);
      //inventory.push(o);
  }
}

function Draggable(elem) {
  this.target = elem
  this.clickPoint = this.target.ownerSVGElement.createSVGPoint()
  this.lastMove = this.target.ownerSVGElement.createSVGPoint()
  this.currentMove = this.target.ownerSVGElement.createSVGPoint()
  this.dpath = this.target.getAttribute("d")
  this.subclass = this.target.getAttribute("subclass")
  this.target.pathPoints = parsePathToPoints(this.dpath, this.subclass)
  this.target.addEventListener("dblclick", this)
  this.target.addEventListener("mousedown", this)
  this.handleEvent = function(evt) {
        switch (evt.type) {
            case 'mousedown':
                evt.preventDefault()
                if (this.target.classList.contains("inventory")) {
                  var spawned = this.target.cloneNode(true);
                  spawned.classList.remove("inventory");
                  spawned.classList.add("draggable");
                  canvas.appendChild(spawned);
                  this.target = spawned;
                  //return;
                }
                this.clickPoint = globalToLocalCoords(evt.clientX, evt.clientY)
                this.target.classList.add("dragged")
                this.target.ownerSVGElement.addEventListener("mousemove", this.move)
                this.target.ownerSVGElement.addEventListener("mouseup", this.endMove)
                //to ensure dblclick is "heard" we delay the pointer trick below by 200ms.
                //setTimeout(function() {this.target.setAttribute("pointer-events", "none")}, 200)
                break;
            case 'dblclick':
                evt.preventDefault()
                if (morphTarget) {
                  if (morphTarget!=this.target) {
                  morphTarget.classList.remove("morphed")
                  this.target.classList.add("morphed")
                  morphTarget = elem;
                  } else {
                    return;
                  }
                } else {
                  morphTarget = elem
                  this.target.classList.add("morphed")
                }
                Morph(this.target);
                break;
        }
  }
  this.move = function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault()
    var p = globalToLocalCoords(evt.clientX, evt.clientY)
    this.currentMove.x = this.lastMove.x + (p.x - this.clickPoint.x)
    this.currentMove.y = this.lastMove.y + (p.y - this.clickPoint.y)
    this.target.setAttribute("transform", "translate(" + this.currentMove.x + "," + this.currentMove.y + ")")
  }.bind(this)
  this.endMove = function(evt) {
    this.lastMove.x = this.currentMove.x
    this.lastMove.y = this.currentMove.y
    this.target.classList.remove("dragged")
    //this.target.setAttribute("pointer-events", "all")
    this.target.ownerSVGElement.removeEventListener("mousemove", this.move)
    this.target.ownerSVGElement.removeEventListener("mouseup", this.endMove)
  }.bind(this)
  function globalToLocalCoords(x, y) {
    var p = elem.ownerSVGElement.createSVGPoint()
    var m = elem.parentNode.getScreenCTM()
    p.x = x
    p.y = y
    return p.matrixTransform(m.inverse())
  }
}

function Morph(elem) {
  console.log(elem); 
}

function parsePathToPoints(d, sub) {
  var darray = [];
  var pathPoints = {};
  switch (sub) {
            case 'circle':
              darray = d.replace(/M|A|Z/g, "").replace(/,/g, " ").split(" ").map(Number);
              pathPoints.p0 = {"x": darray[0], "y": darray[1]};
              pathPoints.p1 = {"x": darray[0]+darray[2], "y": darray[1]-darray[3]};
              pathPoints.p2 = {"x": darray[7], "y": darray[8]};
              pathPoints.p3 = {"x": darray[0]+darray[2], "y": darray[1]+darray[3]};
              pathPoints.p4 = {"x": darray[2], "y": darray[3]}; // = radius used in the circle path
              return pathPoints;
            break;
            case 'curve4':
              darray = d.replace(/M|Q/g, "").replace(/,/g, " ").split(" ").map(Number);
              for (i=0, j=1, o=9; i<darray.length-2; i+=2, j+=2, o++) {
                pathPoints["p"+(o-9)] = {"x": darray[i], "y": darray[j]};
                };
              return pathPoints;
            break;
            case 'curve3':
              darray = d.replace(/M|Q/g, "").replace(/,/g, " ").split(" ").map(Number)
              for (i=0, j=1, o=9; i<darray.length; i+=2, j+=2, o++) {
                pathPoints["p"+(o-9)] = {"x": darray[i], "y": darray[j]};
                }
              return pathPoints;
            break;
            case 'curve2':
              darray = d.replace(/M|Q/g, "").replace(/,/g, " ").split(" ").map(Number);
              for (i=0, j=1, o=9; i<darray.length; i+=2, j+=2, o++) {
                pathPoints["p"+(o-9)] = {"x": darray[i], "y": darray[j]};
                }
              return pathPoints;
            break; 
            case 'curve1':
              darray = d.replace(/M|Q/g, "").replace(/,/g, " ").split(" ").map(Number);
              for (i=0, j=1, o=9; i<darray.length; i+=2, j+=2, o++) {
                pathPoints["p"+(o-9)] = {"x": darray[i], "y": darray[j]};
                }
              return pathPoints;
            break;
            case 'cubic':
              darray = d.replace(/M|C/g, "").replace(/,/g, " ").split(" ").map(Number);
              for (i=0, j=1, o=9; i<darray.length; i+=2, j+=2, o++) {
                    pathPoints["p"+(o-9)] = {"x": darray[i], "y": darray[j]};
               }
              return pathPoints;
            break; 
    }
}

function pointsToPath(pathPoints, pathSubclass) {
    console.log("joining "+pathPoints+"for a "+pathSubclass);
}
```

```css
html, body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 overflow:hidden;
 background-color: #fff; 
}
svg {
    position: fixed; 
   top:0%; 
   left:0%; 
   width:100%; 
   height:100%;  
}
.inventory {
  fill: transparent;
 stroke: black;
  cursor: move;
}
.draggable {
  fill: transparent;
 stroke: blue;
  cursor: move;
}
.dragged {
  fill: transparent;
 stroke: green;
  cursor: move;
}
.morphed {
  fill: transparent;
 stroke: red;
  cursor: move;
}
.lines {
 stroke: green;
  stroke-dasharray: 8,5;
  stroke-width: 1;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
path
{
 stroke-width: 3;
 stroke: #000;
 stroke-linecap: round;
}
path.fill
{
 fill: #3ff;
}
#canvasBackground {
 fill: lightgrey;
}
#inventoryBackground {
 fill: grey;
}
#morphUIrect {
    fill: none; 
    stroke: blue;
    stroke-dasharray: 10,5;
    opacity: 0.1;
}
.label {
  fill: grey;
}
```

```html
<body>
<svg id="svg"
  height="480"
  width="480"
 viewbox="0 0 480 580"
 preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMax meet"
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
>
<rect id="canvasBackground" width="480" height="480" x="0" y="0" pointer-events="all"/>
<rect id="inventoryBackground" width="480" height="100" x="0" y="480" pointer-events="all"/>

<g id="inventory">
<path class="inventory" subclass="circle" d="M30,530 A35,35 1 1,1 100,530 A35,35 1 1,1 30,530" />
<path class="inventory" subclass="curve4" d="M125,500 Q155,490 185,500 Q195,530 185,560 Q155,570 125,560 Q115,530 125,500" />
<path class="inventory" subclass="curve3" d="M245,495 Q275,520 280,560 Q245,570 210,560 Q215,520 245,495" />
<path class="inventory" subclass="curve2" d="M305,515 Q345,475 385,515 Q345,555 305,515"/>
<path class="inventory" subclass="curve1" d="M305,550 Q345,580 385,550"/>
<path class="inventory" subclass="cubic" d="M420,495 C470,530 380,530 425,565"/>
</g>

<g id="canvas">
</g>
  
<g id="morphUI">
<rect id="morphUIrect" visibility = "visible" x="0" y="0" width="0" height="0"></rect>
<line id="l0" visibility = "hidden" class="lines" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="0"/>
<line id="l1" visibility = "hidden" class="lines" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="0"/>
<line id="l2" visibility = "hidden" class="lines" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="0"/>
<line id="l3" visibility = "hidden" class="lines" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="0"/>
<line id="l4" visibility = "hidden" class="lines" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="0"/>
<line id="l5" visibility = "hidden" class="lines" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="0"/>
<line id="l6" visibility = "hidden" class="lines" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="0"/>
<line id="l7" visibility = "hidden" class="lines" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="0"/>
<circle id="0" visibility = "hidden" class="control" cx="0" cy="0" r="8"/>
<circle id="1" visibility = "hidden" class="control" cx="0" cy="0" r="8"/>
<circle id="2" visibility = "hidden" class="control" cx="0" cy="0" r="8"/>
<circle id="3" visibility = "hidden" class="control" cx="0" cy="0" r="8"/>
<circle id="4" visibility = "hidden" class="control" cx="0" cy="0" r="8"/>
<circle id="5" visibility = "hidden" class="control" cx="0" cy="0" r="8"/>
<circle id="6" visibility = "hidden" class="control" cx="0" cy="0" r="8"/>
<circle id="7" visibility = "hidden" class="control" cx="0" cy="0" r="8"/>
<circle id="8" visibility = "hidden" class="control" cx="0" cy="0" r="10" _x="0" _y="0"/>
</g>
</svg>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's usually better not to attach event handlers to individual SVG shape elements.  If you move fast while dragging, then release the mouse button, the mouseup event can happen outside the shape you are dragging. And you can end up with "stuck" shapes.  It is better to attach the mouseup/mousedown events to the root `<svg>` element and keep track of which element you are dragging in a variable. This also has the benefit that you don't have to keep adding and removing event handlers from the dragged elements.

Comment: Hey Paul, thank you for your comment. I understand your suggestion, but I think I want yet to focus on solving spawning technique first. Like how to make it properly. Clone or not to clone? which one element to drag, the cloned or the original etc